# How to set typeIdPropertyName in MappingJackson2MessageConverter

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

With `Spring4 + ActiveMQ` I want to receive a JMS Message from a Queue and convert to POJO automatically.  I added the `MappingJackson2MessageConverter` to `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory`:

```
@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();

    // some other config

    MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
    converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("???");
    factory.setMessageConverter(converter);

    return factory;
}
```

And this is my Listener Config

```
@JmsListener(destination = "queue.fas.flight.order", containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")
public void processOrder(OrderRegisterDto registerParam) {
    System.out.println(registerParam.toString());
}
```

My question is, how do I set `TypeIdPropertyName`? The Queue is not under my control; others send `JSON` to it.

I want a **common converter** so I am using `String` receive message and am converting it to a POJO manually.

```
@JmsListener(destination = "xxxx", containerFactory = "xxxxx")
 public void order(String registerParam) {
    try{
        OrderRegisterDto dto = objectMapper.readValue(registerParam,OrderRegisterDto.class);
    }catch (IOException e){
        // TODO
    }
}
```

Are there any other better methods?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The converter expects the sender to provide type information for the conversion in a message property.

```
String typeId = message.getStringProperty(this.typeIdPropertyName);
```

The typeId can be a class name, or a key for an entry in the typeId mapping map.

If your message does not contain any type information, you need to subclass the converter and override `getJavaTypeForMessage()` to return a Jackson `JavaType` for the target class, e.g.:

```
return TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructType(Foo.class);
```

If it's a constant and not dependent on some information in the message, you can create a static field in your subclass.

Comment: First, yes, it works.
ths subClass like this:
`@Override
protected JavaType getJavaTypeForMessage(Message message) throws JMSException {
    return TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructType(OrderRegisterDto.class);
}`
But I want a **common converter**. 
With this method, only `OrderRegisterDto.class` can be convert, what about else, add another `ListenerFactory`?
So I use `String` receive message, and convert it to POJO manually.
`OrderRegisterDto dto = objectMapper.readValue(registerParam,OrderRegisterDto.class);`
Does any more better method?

Comment: Don't try to put code in comments, edit the question instead. You can make the converter subclass as sophisticated as you want - but you need some hint in the message to tell you what class to create.

Comment: is it possible to determine the type not from the message itself but from the target type of the @JmsListener annotated method? It is actually the expected behavior in comparison to standard deserialization that occur in controllers for example.

Comment: We recently added logic to [Spring AMQP](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.6.0.RELEASE/reference/html/_introduction.html#_json_messageconverter) to do that (infer the type from the `@RabbitListener`) method, but it's not available for `@JmsListener`; you need to configure the converter manually.

Answer (score 0):

This work:

```
@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {

    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();

    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);


    factory.setConcurrency("3-10");


    // Este es el convertidor por defeto de Spring.
    SimpleMessageConverter s = new SimpleMessageConverter();

    MappingJackson2MessageConverter s2 = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    s2.setTargetType(MessageType.BYTES);
    s2.setTypeIdPropertyName("DocumentType");

    factory.setMessageConverter(s2);  // or "s"

    return factory;
}
```

This is the listener:

```
@JmsListener(containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory", destination = ORDER_QUEUE)
@Payload final ) {
public void receiveMessage(Session ses, @Payload final Message<Product> message, @Headers final Map<String, Object> headers)  {


}
```

And the Javascript STOMP client:

```
 var product = {
              productId : "111",
              name : "laptop",
              quantity: 2
            }
 var beforeSend = JSON.stringify(product);
 stompClient.send(destinationProductProd_02,{"DocumentType":"org.jms.model.Product"}, beforeSend);  // OK
```

Observe that I add the "DocumentType" STOMP header to the message to send. You need send the full package path of the Java class.

Comment: thx, that's could be fine if the `queue` under my control. But actually, someone else send the message to the `queue`, it's impossible to add an extra param like "DocumentType" or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no simple solution to automatically convert the JSON to POJO in **@JmsListener** without the "type header" in a message. But it is possible to do it in your code explicitly using Jackson's ObjectMapper:

```
@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@JmsListener(destination = "...", containerFactory = "...")
public void processOrder(String payload) {
    OrderRegisterDto dto = objectMapper.readValue(payload, OrderRegisterDto.class);
    System.out.println(dto.toString());
}
```

Don't forget to remove **MappingJackson2MessageConverter** in your config:

> <strike>MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();</strike>
>   <strike>factory.setMessageConverter(converter);</strike>

Answer (score 0):

Jackson need type info to convert the JSON to POJO;
use `@JsonTypeInfo` can generate class type info in JSON automatically
so i use the this way solve this problem:

1. define a abstract class with `@JsonTypeInfo`

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, property = "@class")
public abstract class AbstractMessage implements Serializable {

}
```

2. define POJO extends `AbstractMessage`

```java
public class Xxx extends AbstractMessage {
    // some properties
}
```

3. config the MessageConverter

```java
@Bean
public MessageConverter messageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2MessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    messageConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    // same with @JsonTypeInfo( property )
    messageConverter.setTypeIdPropertyName("@class");
    return messageConverter;
}
```